# Lodash get nested object property with pluck

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var characters = [
    { 'name': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'salary':{'amount': 10} },
    { 'name': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'salary':{'amount': 20} },
    { 'name': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'salary':{'amount': 30} }
];
```

I want to get the salary amounts into an array. I managed to do it by chaining two `pluck` functions, like this:

```
var salaries = _(characters)
  .pluck('salary')
  .pluck('amount')
  .value();

console.log(salaries); //[10, 20, 30]
```

Is there a way to do this by using only one `pluck`? Is there a better way with some other function in lodash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just give the path to be used as a string, like this

```
console.log(_(characters).pluck('salary.amount').value())
// [ 10, 20, 30 ]
```

Or use it directly

```
console.log(_.pluck(characters, 'salary.amount'));
// [ 10, 20, 30 ]
```

Comment: pluck method is now deprecated, instead you can use _.map() for Arrays and _.get() to get a single value of an object using a string like "salary.amount"

Comment: _.map(characters, 'salary.amount')